# Setting and using dynamic variable name JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I can't figure out how to use the name of a variable previously created with `eval`, without knowing it.
I mean:

```
function getName(menu_name, level){  
    eval("var menu_"+level+"="+menu_name);  
}
```

Now how do I get the name of the variable I just created? Probably keep using `eval`, but I have to put that name into a `$.post` call as one of my field name.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: If you want to get the name of the variable that you just created, then use the same code that you used to create it in the first place! … but don't do that. `eval` is evil. Variable variables are evil. JavaScript has proper data structures you can use. (See duplicate question).

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? It causes a lot of headaches and isn't really worth it. Just use an array.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I don't know the value of 'level', since it's sent through PHP. What I'm trying to do is having menu_0 the first time, menu_1 the second and so on, where 0,1 are the values of level sent through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If `level` is an integer, you can treat it as a numerical index for an array:

```
var menu = [];
menu[level] = menu_name;
```

If `level` is anything else, you can treat it as a key for a dictionary/associative array:

```
var menu = {};
menu[level] = menu_name;
```

Then, for either of the solutions, if you want to access your `menu_name`, simply call `menu[level]`.

Comment: Level is an integer, but I keep having problems when I try to do this:   $.post('url.php', {menu_level : menu_name}, function(e){...});

Comment: @user2694388 What's the issue?

Comment: Let's put it in other words. I want to create the name of a new variable from two strings, the first being "menu_" and the second being sent through PHP and being "level". Obviously I cannot simply put them together. The problem is because I cannot change the input name in the html form, and as far as I know the parameter I write in the $.post call must be the same as the input name.

Comment: Just don't create another variable; use the `menu` array and access the right index.

Comment: Well then probably I'm not getting that. In PHP it is much easier since you can use ${$var} to create the variable when you don't know its value. The problem is putting that name into the $.post call, can you help me?